# Eslint error when compiling vue file with loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to make a dynamic page with Vue3. I created a Projects.json file with an array with data. This data I want to display on the MainContainerContent.vue file. I made a v-for inside the App.vue and in the MainContainer.vue to loop over the projects in the json file.

I'm now having the problem that I get this error on the v-for: `Custom elements in iteration require 'v-bind:key' directives` it says it has to do with eslint-plugin-vue. I already did run the command: `npm remove @vue/cli-plugin-eslint` but I'm still getting this error when compiling.

Could anyone explain to me how I can get rid of this error? Since with this error I can't run my application so I can't test if the code I wrote is working.

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <MainContainer/>

  <section
    class="flex flex-col items-center pb-8"
    v-for="project in projects">
      <h2
      role="title"
      class="text-3xl font-bold"
      >{{ project.name }}</h2>
      <MainContainer
      :project="project"
      />
    </section>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { projects } from './Projects.json'
  import MainContainer from './components/mainContainer.vue';
  import './assets/tailwind.css';
</script>
```

**MainContainer.vue**

```
<template>
  <Header/>
  <Content
    v-for="project in projects.project"
    :project="project"
  />
</template>

<script setup>
  import Header from './mainContainerHeader.vue';
  import Content from './mainContainerContent.vue';
</script>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    projects: {
      default: null,
      type: Object,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**MainContainerContent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p
      class="p-3 border-r-2 border-r-gray-500"
      >{{ project.name }}</p>
      <p
      class="p-3 border-r-2 border-r-gray-500"
      >{{ project.description }}</p>
      <p
      class="p-3"
      >{{ project.link }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    project: {
      default: null,
      type: Object,
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Projects.json**

```
{
  "projects": [
    {
      "name": "Projects",
      "project": [
        {
          "name": "Project #1",
          "description": "Project #1",
          "link": "www.google.be"
        },
        {
          "name": "Project #2",
          "description": "Project #2",
          "link": "www.google.be"
          }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would reccomend to address and fix the error :)

The error is telling you that a key binding is missing, this helps Vue to track each item. See more at: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/list.html#maintaining-state-with-key

So simply add the key directive and set the value to something unique.

```
<section
    class="flex flex-col items-center pb-8"
    v-for="project in projects"
    :key="project.name"
>
```

Assuming the name is unique, you could also add an id property to your json file and use that as a key.